# ¿Cómo Usar index de la tabla nombre?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

estoy estudiando indices en bases de datos y tengo una tabla de prueba como esta y he indexado con la columna nombre y código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Use la sentencia create index nombre on usuario(nombre) al igual con el código  create index código on usuario (código).

Esto es lo que me arroja cuando escribo show index from usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Cómo puedo saber si una consulta esta usando el índice nombre?

Comment: Para esta prueba me gustaría indexar el nombre y el código, use un create index nombre on usuario(nombre), pero no sé si las consultas usan el index cuando busco por nombre

Answer (score 1):

Yo te haría los siguientes comentarios:

1. Es raro usar el motor [**MyISAM**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) cuando tiene algunas implicaciones tales como:

   - No existe soporte para *llaves foráneas*
   - No esta optimizado al no contar con un [*clustered index*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-introduction.html)
   - Ya no es el motor por *default* usado al momento de crear las tablas
   - De hecho para el punto anterior si ejecutas el siguiente comando verás una tabla con los motores que puedes emplear y aquel que esta configurado por *default* para ser usado

     ```
     SHOW ENGINES;
     ```
2. Para poder indexar la columna de `Nombre`, debería alcanzar con llevar a cabo lo siguiente:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE ....(
       ................,
       ................,
       Nombre VARCHAR(50),
       INDEX (Nombre)
   );
   ```

   - Si ahora ejecutas una consulta similar a la siguiente:

     ```
     EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ..... WHERE Nombre = '....' AND Codigo = '.....'
     ```
   - Verás un resultado como el siguiente:

     ```
           *************************** 1. row ***************************
                      id: 1
             select_type: SIMPLE
                   table: ...
                    type: const
           possible_keys: PRIMARY,Nombre
                     key: PRIMARY
                 key_len: 4
                     ref: const
                    rows: 1
                   Extra:
           1 row in set (0.001 sec)
     ```
   - Y la salida será muy similar aún cuando la columna *`Nombre`* no esté indexada pero la columna *`Código`* si  (**Ojo! digo que la salida sería similar siempre y cuando *`Código`* si esté presente en la consulta, en caso contrario la salida será muy parecida al ejemplo siguiente**)
   - En cambio si por ejemplo *tu columna *`Código`* y *`Nombre`* no fueran índice* o solo consultas por Nombre y esta no se encuentra indexada entonces ejecutar la misma nos devolvería esto siguiente:

     ```
          *************************** 1. row ***************************
                     id: 1
            select_type: SIMPLE
                  table: ....
                   type: ALL
          possible_keys: NULL
                    key: NULL
                key_len: NULL
                    ref: NULL
                   rows: 3
                  Extra: Using where
          1 row in set (0.001 sec)
     ```
3. Diferencias y aspectos en los que debes prestar especial atención:

- Entre el primer y segundo *`EXPLAIN`* están elementos como las *posibles keys* usadas
- El *número de filas* que se tuvieron que analizar
- Lo que MySQL tuvo que emplear para determinar como solucionaría la consulta

**Edición**

- Revisa en la propia [doc. oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information) cuales son los **únicos casos** en los que verás información en la columna extra

**Fuentes de referencia**

- Debes profundizar mas en el tema de [los índices](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)
- Lee esta fuente [sobre la salida y su explicación de **EXPLAIN**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-output-columns)
- Creación de [índices](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html)

Comment: oye amigo he hecho algunos ejercicios con nombre indexado y buscando solo por nombre y veo que te sale lo mismo que a mi pero mi duda es porque si nombre esta indexado en la columna extra del explain a veces sale null, a veces sale using where y otras veces si sale using index? que se tiene que hacer para que siempre una consulta que busque por nombre use el use el indice de nombre??

Comment: acabo de leer lo de using index de la pagina que me pasaste y a lo que entendi es que en la columna extra solo sale el using index cuando la busqueda solo usa valores que estan en un indice por ende si yo hago una consulta "Select titulo from usuario where codigo = 1", la columna de extra saldra en null, ya que titulo no esta indexada, entonces en si que significa null?

Comment: @LuisGarcia revisa la edición que haré